# Displaying comments under specific posts

Tags: php, html, mysqli, comments, posts

im trying to assign a list of posts with a comment section that is unique to that post. My problem is that instead of displaying specific comments under specific posts, all the comments are displayed on every single post.

Im using 2 database tables: "posts: id, title, subtitle, content" 
and "comments: comment_id, post_fk (foreign key attached to the posts id), uid, date, message.

**blog.php, where posts are echoed and comments are submitted and then posted through getComments**

```
// fetch data from posts and echo them into a post

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $title = $row['title'];
    $subtitle = $row['subtitle'];
    $content = $row['content'];
?>
    <h2><?php echo $title; ?> - <small><?php echo $subtitle; ?></small></h2>
    <p><?php echo $content; ?></p>

// echo the comment field and then get comments from the getComments function echo
echo    "<form method='posts' action='".setComments($conn)."'>
            <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='Anonymous'>
            <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
            <textarea name='message'></textarea><br>
            <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Comment</button>
    </form>";

        getComments($conn);
```

**comments.php, where the setComments and getComments functions are defined**

```
function setComments($conn) {
if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])) {

    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message) VALUES ('$uid', '$date', '$message')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}

function getComments($conn) {
    $sql = "SELECT
    c.uid, 
    c.date,
    c.message 
FROM comments AS c  
    LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON
    c.post_fk = p.id
    WHERE c.post_fk = p.id
";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['uid'];
        echo $row['date']."<br><br>";
        echo $row['message']."<br><br>";
```

I have been experimenting with the LEFT JOIN without any promising results. Im very new to PHP, but im suspecting that I have to add some additional values to the comment form that determines which post the comment belongs to. I hope this information is substantial enough and sorry if my code is messy!

Thank you

(edit)
**setcomment.php**

```
function setComments($conn) {
if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])) {
    $comment_id = $_POST['comment_id'];
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (comment_id, uid, date, message) VALUES ($comment_id, $uid, $date, $message)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iiss", $id, $uid, $date, $message);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
}
```

[comments table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueEFr.png)
[posts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO2jb.png)

Comment: You can't call a PHP function in `action=`. That has to be a URL to a script that performs the desired action.

Answer (score 0):

`getComments()` needs a parameter that specifies which post you want the comments from, and then it needs a `WHERE` clause that only gets comments from that post.

There's no need to join with the `posts` table in `getComments`, since it's not using anything from that table.

```
function getComments($conn, $post) {
    $sql = "SELECT
        c.uid, 
        c.date,
        c.message 
    FROM comments AS c
    WHERE c.post_id = $post
    ORDER BY c.date
    ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['uid'];
        echo $row['date']."<br><br>";
        echo $row['message']."<br><br>";
    }
}
```

Then you call it as:

```
getComments($conn, $row['id']);
```

In the form,

```
action='".setComments($conn)."'>
```

makes no sense. The `action` attribute has to contain the URL of a script that processes all the form fields. You're calling the `setComments()` function when creating the page, and putting its return value (which is empty, since it has no `return` statement) in the `action` attribute. That should be something like:

```
action='setComments.php'>
```

You can then add a hidden field to the form with the post ID:

```
<input name='postid' type='hidden' value='{$row['id']}'>
```

`setComments.php` can then use `$_POST['postid']` to get the proper `post_id` of the comment being entered. The `setComments` function should look like this (using a prepared statement to protect against SQL-injection):

```
function setComments($conn) {
    if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])) {
        $id = $_POST['postid'];
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];


        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (post_id, uid, date, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iiss", $id, $uid, $date, $message);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
}
```

Comment: im struggling a bit to understand how the setComments.php should look like. Should I take anything from the setComments function that I already have in my comments.php and paste that in? Or do I only want the form fields in the script? How would I integrate $_POST['postid'] into the form in that case?

Comment: I've added the corrected `setComments` function to my answer.

Comment: After having implemented the code into setcomments.php and added the values, this appears on the url when i try to submit a comment: setcomments.php?uid=Anonymous&date=2018-05-11+02%3A43%3A39&message=fjdfd&postid=6&commentSubmit=. When I check the database table I cant see any differences either. I have updated my question with the updated code of the setComments function that you provided as well as pictures of the two tables, although I cant see any mistakes in the values that are set. My apologies for taking your time

Comment: You have a typo: `method='posts'` should be `method='post'`.

Comment: That's causing it to be sent as a `GET` instead of `POST`.

Comment: That fixed the url-text, but there are still no changes to the database. I will try to adjust the insert values and hope the problem is there somewhere

Comment: Are you sure the `setComments()` function is being called? Add error checking to the mysqli calls in `setComments()`.